# Pynput mouse events on_scroll only returns 0 when scrolling right horizontally

Tags: python, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, pynput

I am using pynput in python to detect horizontal scrolling with the touchpad (or other horizontal scrolling things).
[Here are the docs for what I am using.](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#:%7E:text=on_scroll%20(callable)%20%E2%80%93,listener%20is%20stopped.)
I am starting the listener and setting the callback function:

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener

class horizontalScrollListener:
    def __init__(self):
        listener = Listener(on_scroll=lambda xCoord, yCoord, scrollX, scrollY: self.onHorizontalScroll(xCoord, yCoord, scrollX, scrollY))
        listener.start()
    def onHorizontalScroll(self, xCoord, yCoord, scrollX, scrollY):
        print("Scrolled!")
        print(scrollX)
        print(scrollY)
```

When I scroll to the left with the touchpad, it returns a bunch of events, most with the distance scrolled being -1 units (1 unit to the left).
[image: When scrolling left]

However, when I scroll to the right, it returns a bunch of events, but almost all of them say 0.
[image: When I scroll right]

A couple of them are more than 0, but most of them are 0.
This is very annoying, as when I run my actual app and try to use the scrolling, it is basically unusable when scrolling right, but fine when scrolling left.

**Why is this happening?**

Comment: could be timing/threshold things - Idea to also output X,Y, and see if there is an alternative way to get (similar) values?

Comment: shorter `Listener(on_scroll=self.onHorizontalScroll)`

Comment: Furas - Thank you, I could do that, but in my actual thing I want to have extra arguments anyway.

Comment: xCoord and yCoord are just the coordinates of the scroll, which reveals nothing about how much the user scrolled.

Comment: @WillemHendriks what do you mean about timing/threshold things?